# Seeking better virtualenv/rvm/zsh conditional integration

Tags: ruby, rvm, zsh

**tldr:** I want `zsh` to ignore rvm reporting system ruby and only display it when rvm is actually being used.

I've been using `zsh` with the terrific `oh-my-zsh` extensions for some time now. It's got my prompt looking like this, with the **`gnzh`** theme included with `oh-my-zsh`:

```
╭─emergent@elysian ~/devel/octopress ‹ruby-1.9.3› ‹source*› 
╰─➤
```

Note the `‹ruby-1.9.3› ‹source*›` -- that of course is the `zsh` theme doing some things in order to sort me out with the version that `rvm` is using as well as the current branch of the `git` repo.

I've also been playing around with getting this to work with python's `virtualenv` using the `virtualenvwrapper` plugin, as well as [a few tweaks within `virtualenvwrapper` itself in order to avoid it simply prepending `(virtualenv)` at the start of my `$PROMPT`](http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tips.html#zsh-prompt).

I like this because it only shows an indication when I've changed my directory into a `virtualenv` and activated it (which `virtualenvwrapper`/`zsh` automagically does for me). However, this doesn't work well when I shift things into a `virtualenv` and the path names start getting longer. For example:

```
╭─emergent@elysian ~PROJECT_HOME/djangotutorial/mysite/polls ‹djangotutorial› ‹system› ‹tu
torial02*›
╰─➤
```

My terminal is only 88 characters wide, and as such, my prompt theme (including `virtualenvwrapper`, `rvm` and `git` information) is being spread over 3 lines.

The solution I've been trying is to only display an `rvm` indicator when I've actually got an `rvm ruby` activated. I don't find myself ever using the two at the same time, and having `‹system›` appended to each one of my prompt lines seems ultimately superfluous.

This is what I've tried amending my `.zsh-theme` in order to achieve this:

```
local rvm_ruby=''
# Tests for existence of RVM
if which rvm-prompt &> /dev/null; then
  # !!! THIS IS THE EDIT TO THE THEME I'M ATTEMPTING: !!!
  # Tests if it's using the system ruby and only displays when RVM is
  # actually being used.
  if [ $(rvm-prompt i v g s) != "system" ]; then
    rvm_ruby='%{$PR_RED%}‹$(rvm-prompt i v g s)›%{$PR_NO_COLOR%}'
  fi
else
  if which rbenv &> /dev/null; then
    rvm_ruby='%{$PR_RED%}‹$(rbenv version | sed -e "s/ (set.*$//")›%{$PR_NO_COLOR%}'
  fi
fi
local git_branch='$(git_prompt_info)%{$PR_NO_COLOR%}'

#PROMPT="${user_host} ${current_dir} ${rvm_ruby} ${git_branch}$PR_PROMPT "
PROMPT="╭─${user_host} ${current_dir} ${rvm_ruby} ${git_branch}
╰─$PR_PROMPT "
```

However, it doesn't do anything at all --- I can't see any difference before and after this edit. I've ensured that I am `source`ing `~/.zshrc`. I tested the conditional evaluation in a smaller script, and it seemed to work out:

```
if [ $(rvm-prompt i v g s) != "system" ]; then
  echo $(rvm-prompt i v g s)
fi

╭─emergent@elysian ~/devel/shellscripts ‹system› 
╰─➤  ./test.sh
╭─emergent@elysian ~/devel/shellscripts ‹system› 
╰─➤  rvm use ruby-1.9.3
Using /home/emergent/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392
╭─emergent@elysian ~/devel/shellscripts ‹ruby-1.9.3› 
╰─➤  ./test.sh         
ruby-1.9.3
```

Anyone who's more experienced with messing about with shell stuff have any ideas as to what I might be able to do better here? Even if your suggestion is to tell me to do something totally different from what I'm up to now in the interest of increased utility and productivity, I'm down to hear it. Cheers and thanks in advance!

Comment: The arrow as you're seeing it there is what came with oh-my-zsh, although that's just what the terminal looks like on my linux box. On OSX I've got it looking more like this, because the terminal on OSX seems to pull off unicode a bit better. Imagine a newline after the ~ :

@Ds-MacBook.local ~
⤷

Comment: I suggest a TL;DR for your question if you want it to get answered.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I understand that it wasn't exactly the most concise explanation for what I had to say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got this:

```
if which rvm-prompt &> /dev/null; then
  if [ $(rvm-prompt i v g s) != "system" ]; then
    rvm_ruby='%{$PR_RED%}‹$(rvm-prompt i v g s)›%{$PR_NO_COLOR%}'
  fi
else
  # We don't have `rvm-prompt`, try using `rbenv` instead.
fi
```

Let's have a look at what this is actually doing. When you open a new terminal, `zsh` loads a bunch of files, including `~/.zshrc`. In your `~/.zshrc`, you're `source`ing the `theme`. Thus, as `zsh` loads, it runs through the edit you've made.

The first thing it'll check is whether or not it can find `rvm-prompt` using the `zsh` [builtin] `which`. It does this by checking the `return code` of `which` (if `0`, continue). (Not finding `rvm-prompt` is a different issue, and not really related to this answer).

If we **do** find `rvm-prompt`, using your edit we then examine whether or not the output of `rvm-prompt i v g s` is `system`. It's not, so we set `$rvm_ruby` to **contain a call to `rvm-prompt`**.

Then, `zsh` continues loading the theme, finally finishing and setting `$PROMPT` to a bunch of stuff, **including a call to `rvm-prompt`**. It's very useful to remember that `zsh` does **not** re-examine the theme logic! (That's why we need to `source ~/path/to/theme` after editing it)!

So what's the problem? If `rvm-prompt` does not say `system` **on shell startup**, we use output from  `rvm-prompt` for the remainder of the session in our prompt. (If `rvm-prompt` *was* system, we wouldn't display any `rvm` indicator in our prompt... because `rvm_ruby` is left blank!).

Now that we understand what's happening, we can work on fixing it. There are two approaches I can think of.

#### 1. Strip the word `system` out of the prompt:

```
if which rvm-prompt &> /dev/null; then
  rvm_ruby='%{$PR_RED%}‹$(rvm-prompt i v g s | sed -e "s/system//")›%{$PR_NO_COLOR%}'
else
  # We don't have `rvm-prompt`, try using `rbenv` instead.
fi
```

This works, but will display a (red) `<>` in your prompt when `rvm-prompt` is `system`:

```
╭─@charmander.local ~ ‹ruby-1.9.3›
╰─ rvm default
╭─@charmander.local ~ ‹ruby-1.9.3›
╰─ rvm use system
Now using system ruby.
╭─@charmander.local ~ ‹›
╰─
```

You might find this useful. I think it would annoy me.

#### 2. Use a smarter `$PROMPT`: write a function.

In your `theme`:

```
function current_rvm() {
  if which rvm-prompt &> /dev/null; then
    if [ $(rvm-prompt i v g s) != "system" ]; then
      # The double quotes make it work, single quotes do not work.
      echo "%{$PR_RED%}‹$(rvm-prompt i v g s)›%{$PR_NO_COLOR%}"
    else
      # `rvm-prompt` is `system`
      echo ''
    fi
  else
    # We don't have `rvm-prompt`, try using `rbenv` instead.
  fi
}
local rvm_ruby='$(current_rvm)'
```

This should work happily for you:

```
╭─@charmander.local ~ ‹ruby-1.9.3›
╰─ rvm use system
Now using system ruby.
╭─@charmander.local ~
╰─ rvm use default
Using /Users/simont/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362
╭─@charmander.local ~ ‹ruby-1.9.3›
╰─
```

Comment: Right on! I had been mucking about with some sort of function and didn't get anywhere with it, but had a good idea that it was the right way to go. Thanks for coming up with a solution :)

Comment: I've added a small edit -- On the echo return from current_rvm(), if it's not encapsulated in double quotes it'll give me a prompt that looks like emergent@elysian ~/devel/octopress $PR_RED‹$(rvm-prompt i v g s)›$PR_NO_COLOR ‹source› . Changing the echo statement's quotations does the trick to make things work.